# How do i configure the New Item Form to contain an option to save a list item as a draft

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am looking to accomplish the following on my list form. New Item would have 3 buttons, like saveDraft, submit and cancel. When the form is submitted it will be viewable by all users but if a user just saves as draft it is only viewable to the person submitting the form?

Comment: look into the "Check in" feature for documents

Comment: Why are you trying to put them as buttons? Instead make a field with choice of Draft or Final... And play with view filters to show Draft only to CreatedBy = [Me] and only show Final to other users!

Comment: Please make sure to mark answers as having helped you solve your issue. Otherwise other members of this community may not be willing to answer your questions in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead recommend putting a simple Yes / No check box on your form. Default it to Yes (*checked*) and that column would be called "Save as draft?". Adding an actual button control at the bottom of the form isn't impossible but, a lot of extra work when it can just as easily be accomplished via a check box.